# WPF Prism + Existing WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I've an existing application.

With about 3 years of good experience with WPF/MVVM - I feel I should have started with Prism (I've no knowledge of PRISM framework as of now - and I plan to learn it now).

Goals are to -
- Make the appication a SOLID (design) based framework. Existing code is mix of MVVM (recent new features) and code behind model (existing features)

Since it's a massive application - moving everything to Prism would be quite a task.

Questions:
- I plan to start a new development (a big feature implementation). Can I use Prism for the new development? I am happy to write most of the components from scratch and slowly go function wise to move entire application to Prism.

e.g. Existing front office real time trading application, planning to add back office/middle office functions to it, and slowly move front office functions to Prism.

- I have a feeling that learning PRISM can be as much learning curve as it was moving from winforms to WPF - is that true? any suggestions about Books that I should follow? I am a bit of procedural learner and prefer step by step learning from basics (i.e everything about Prism).
- What are the massive advantages I am going to gain with Prism. Can there be any performance hits at GUI level?

Regards, Vinay

Comment: This question is primarly opinion-based. This does not comply with stackoverflow rules (or any Q&A site for that matter).

Comment: I thought at StackOverFlow, we could seek opinion of experts, no?

Comment: @Kryptos: OP doesn't ask "Is Prism good or bad?". The question is quite correct.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Two people might _fell_ different about using Prism. Stackoverflow questions should be about concrete programming problem, not whether or not it is _good_ to use a software/tool or not. See [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Dennis OP: "Can I use Prism for the new development?" Short answer is, "yes of course why couldn't you?". Other answers are opinion-based, and thus off-topic. "I have a feeling [...] is that true?" == "Do you feel the same?" again opinion-based.

Comment: @Kryptos: this is misunderstanding of the question, or, even worse, a demagogy. OP asks about the way to move existing application to Prism framework without total rewrite it. "New development" is a "a big feature implementation" (C). Please, if you gained "vote to close" privilege, don't try to find close reason in every question.

Comment: @Dennis please read the stackoverflow rules before saying I'm wrong. Using a new piece of software on an existing project really depends on the software itself. Do you think a definite answer can be found here? And how will this help other users having the same question. StackOverflow is meant to build a knowledge base. But the question here is too broad and is more suited in a forum where each users can give their opinion or share their experience with their own projects. I don't say that the question is not legitimate but just that it doesn't fit here.

Comment: Y'know. You don't need a fancy framework to get the MVVM design pattern to work for you. As long as you understand the principles, then frameworks are optional.

Comment: I have good understanding of MVVM/MVP. I would be really thankful, if one of you could help answer the question in a perspective. If this question is not appropriate for this forum - then no other could be. I don't see the any reason why StackOverFlow should not help people asking general Technology related questions. Technologies and frameworks keep changing with time, today there is one good, tomorrow there will be another better - Opinions help people choose the right direction - else Journey of learning becomes very long... @Kryptos - It's sad you are trying to kill the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [the official guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) which by the way begins by defining Prism as follows:

> Prism provides guidance in the form of samples and documentation that
>   help you easily design and build rich, flexible, and easily maintained
>   Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) desktop applications. Using
>   design patterns that embody important architectural design principles,
>   such as separation of concerns and loose coupling, **Prism helps you to
>   design and build applications using loosely coupled components that
>   can evolve independently but which can be easily and seamlessly
>   integrated into the overall application.** In short, these applications
>   are "built to last" and "built for change." These types of
>   applications are known as **composite applications**.

I've highlighted the sentence that I think best summarizes along with the term they use to refer to this kind of applications: composite applications.

If your application could benefit from having loosely coupled modules then Prism may be the way to go. For instance, when developing an ERP, you may choose to implement each relevant functional area as a module. You may want to be more granular and use modules for different parts of the UI such as in the [stock trader reference implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074.aspx).

I haven't found the learning curve to be significantly steep. Indeed, [the guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) is quite well organized and you can go straight to the concepts you require in each moment without having to read the whole thing. By no means is such a change as moving from WinForms to WPF: it builds on the MVVM foundations you are familiar with, adding some higher-level abstractions and using some known patterns such as publisher/subscriber events.

Bottom line is that for decently sized applications, you should gain maintainability by investing in using Prism. Being already proficient in MVVM, the learning should be pretty easy.

**EDIT**: answering comment

> So, I could start a PRISM based GUI set in the existing WPF application?

Absolutely, yes. You can take the bits you find useful, and most likely use more and more eventually. Be advised that you may need to change the initialization of your application to implement the [Bootstrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868(v=pandp.40).aspx). However, it is not compulsory, so just take a look at the patterns and start using those that you see fit. It's not an all-or-nothing framework.

Comment: Many thanks @jnovo, So, I could start a PRISM based GUI set in the existing WPF application? Don't want to ask too much further on that, but just want to have a quick answer in yes/no... Rest I will do by learning.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating an existing app to Prism is quite an undertaking.  Having part of an app be Prism while part of it not be is possible but I think you'll find yourself becoming very frustrated at having to jump back and forth between the 2 worlds and having to find ways to get them to play nicely together.

I personally wouldn't go down this path.  If you are looking to get the benefits of dependency injection, then it would be much easier to gradually adopt a dependency injection library than to adopt the much much larger Prism framework.  Specifically, as you are building new features write them such that their dependencies get injected... initially this code will fail so then you'll go to where each of those dependencies are actually defined and add a line of code to register them with your DI container.

Comment: Many thanks for your Insight Robert. I thought of going down a DI fw path initially. I have written DIs using basic SOLID principles (all new dev).My idea is to write new components and later slowly start migrating as other parts into PRISM. This seems inevitable as existing non MVVM code is quite frustrating to unit test and has lot of dependencies. I do have the intention - Just want to choose the right path for better future and adaptability, are there any other challenges u foresee?

Comment: Or may be, with this advice,  I will create a POC over next couple of weeks, that will be a learning anyways. Many thanks everyone for your inputs!